# How to get after executing INSERT into database fetch id of inserted row?

Tags: c++, postgresql, c++11, libpqxx

I am using c++11 and pqxx to access postgresql database and I need id of inserted row and flag if it was successful or not.
How to get after executing INSERT into database fetch id of inserted row ?
I have tried to find example on net but without success.

```
work txn(*conn);
txn.prepared("insert ")(person_name).exec();
txn.commit();
```

Comment: `insert ... returning`?

Answer (score 2):

```
work txn(*conn);
pqxx::result r = txn.prepared("insert into t (a,b,c) values (1,2,$1) returning id")(person_name).exec();
txn.commit();
int id = r[0][0].as<int>();
```